# Choose text file and Read Android

Tags: android

I chose a text file from storage and got its path (`FilePath`), am trying to read the content of that text file and put it in edittext..i am using the code below to get text file data and put it in edittext (eTPronounce)

```
 File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();


//Get the text filea
                File file = new File(sdcard,FilePath);

//Read text from file
                StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();

                try {
                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
                    String line;

                    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                        text.append(line);
                        text.append('\n');
                    }
                    br.close();
                }
                catch (IOException e) {
                    //You'll need to add proper error handling here
                }

//Find the view by its i

//Set the text
           eTPronounce.setText(text);

            }
        });
```

If i replace  FilePath (in the second line) with any directory where there is text file it works.For example if I replace FilePath with "Download/text.txt" it works .
I used [this](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2011/03/pick-file-using-intentactiongetcontent.html) link to get FilePath

THANKS

Comment: full code http://jpst.it/D5an

Comment: do you add use-permission

Comment: if it reads the file than what is the issue, i think you should check the existence of the file first than try to read it

Comment: i used permissions yes

Comment: Try my code  getData() return a uri

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should be using below constructor

```
File(File dir, String name)
```

or you can use

```
File(String path)
```

If you are specifying directory name then you only need to give the file name as shown in the first example.Otherwise you can use the second one with the complete file path

Comment: so i should replace this    File file = new File(sdcard,FilePath); with this    File file = new File(String,FilePath);

Comment: No use new File(FilePath).

I assume that FilePath is the complete path of the file

Comment: Brooooooooooooooooooo I love you thankssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss

Answer (score 1):

```
if(resultCode==RESULT_OK){
    if(data == null || data.getData == null){
       //Log.e()
      return;
    }
FilePath = getPath(data.getData(),mActivity);
setfilename.setText(FilePath);
}

    public static String getPath(Uri uri,Context ctx) {
        String res = null;
        if(null==uri){
            return res;
        }
        if (uri != null && uri.toString().startsWith("file://")) {
            return uri.toString().substring("file://".length());
        }
        String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = ctx.getContentResolver().query(uri, proj, null, null, null);
        if(cursor!=null){
            if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
                try {
                    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
                    res = cursor.getString(column_index);
                }catch (Exception ignored){
                }finally {
                    closeCursor(cursor);
                }
            }
        }
        closeCursor(cursor);
        return res;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the help !